# Why is there no determiner before wife?

Tags: ellipsis, determiners, obituaries

> Ken was one of nine children of Patrick William Jubb and **wife** Mary
>   Alice (nee Finlayson).  ([The Age](http://www.theage.com.au/national/obituaries/vet-pathologist-had-halfcentury-career-at-melbourne-university-20130505-2j1gh.html))

There’s no determiner like ‘his’ in front of ‘wife.’ Did the paper miss it or is it a possible expression?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it as written. The more verbose way to express it would be "...and **the** wife **of** Mary Alice." Either one is considered acceptable.

Comment: @J.R.: If there *were* to be a "determiner" in OP's example, it would be ***his** wife* (i.e. - *Patrick William Jubb's*, not *Ken's*). Note the original doesn't say *wife **of***, and Ken certainly couldn't be a "wife of Mary", given these are both gender-specific names.

Comment: @Fumble: Yes, you are right, I misread that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Patrick and Mary are coupled, as the children are both of theirs. This is also not a common phrase we use in day-to-day speech but part of a specific tradition of writing obituaries.

Comment: It's not *only* used in obits. [*The show is a comedy about blended families and is based loosely on the lives of famed actors Will Smith **and wife** Jada Pinkett Smith*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22actors+Will+Smith+and+wife%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example (or *The event, hosted by actors Will Smith **and wife** Jada Pinkett Smith, featured acts such as Leona Lewis*, in the same mag 4 years later). Plus "nepotistic company" names like [*Steptoe **and Son***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steptoe_and_Son), and doubtless many other contexts.